# OG "Add people" username predictive searching

Tags: 7, organic-groups

In OG7, I have given one user the role of **overseer** and that role has the **Administer Organic groups permissions** enabled so he can administer all Organic Groups on the site.

So, for each group, when my overseer goes to *Group* -> *Add People* and he attempts to input the **user name**, the textfield does not predict/provide suggestions of matching user names. However, this helpful effect does happen for the site administrator.

**Can anyone tell me how I can enable this user name prediction effect for my overseer role?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission to set is "View user profiles".